# Events not triggered when pressing home button on mobile devices

Tags: android, iphone, ajax, ipad

When the users access my website from their iPhone, iPad or Android device, if they press the "home button", neither the `blur` nor `beforeunload` events are triggered. I can't log how much time they've been reading the displayed content, as the server is never notified (via ajax call from the events).

On desktop computers it works as expected, while on mobile devices it only works if they close the browser (actually kill it) or they click a link. The problem is "minifying" it through the home button. Is there something to do here?

```
function notifyEndReading() {
  if (readingId != null && !endReading) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'end_read_content' %}",
      type: "post",
      data: {"id": readingId},
      async: false,
      success: function() {
        endReading = true;
      }
    });
  }
}

$(window).blur(function() {
  notifyEndReading();
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  notifyEndReading();
});
```